# Passing filename to a method in Clojure

Tags: input, parameters, clojure, args

I have a filename at args[0] (e.g. (first args) and I want to pass it from my main method to the *slurp-std-input* . I tried to do the followings but I get this error:

*CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: enc in this context, compiling:(regexdna/core.clj:19:3)*

The code for both methods is:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [content (slurp-std-input (first args))
        original-len (count content)
        ;; I'd prefer if I could use the regexp #"(^>.*)?\n" like the
        ;; Perl benchmark does, but that only matches ^ at the beginning
        ;; of the string, not at the beginning of a line in the middle
        ;; of the string.
        content (str/replace content #"(^>.*|\n>.*)?\n" "")
        dna-seq-only-len (count content)]

    (doseq [[re num-matches] (pmap #(count-regex-occurrences % content)
                                   dna-seq-regexes)]
      (spit "./scratch/output.txt" (format "%s %d\n" re num-matches):append true))

    (let [content (reduce one-replacement content iub-codes)]
      (spit "./scratch/output.txt" (format "\n%d\n%d\n%d\n" original-len dna-seq-only-len (count content)) :append true)))
  (flush))
```

and the method in which I want to pass the (first args) parameter, so I can read from the String filename that is contained in (first args) is:

```
(defn slurp-std-input [args]
  ;; Reads the standard input using the encoding enc into a string and
  ;; returns it.
  ([] (slurp-std-input (.name (java.nio.charset.Charset/defaultCharset))))
  ([#^String enc]
     (with-open [r (new java.io.BufferedReader (clojure.java.io/reader args))]
       (let [sb (new StringBuilder)]
     (loop [c (.read r)]
       (if (neg? c)
         (str sb)
         (do
           (.append sb (char c))
           (recur (.read r)))))))))
```

Note that I have changed reading from *in* to reading from my file contained in args[o]

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid syntax.  If you are providing multiple implementations of a method with different arities, the proper syntax would be something like I've put below.  Essentially, the args you had on the first line was incorrect.

```
(defn slurp-std-input
  ;; Reads the standard input using the encoding enc into a string and
  ;; returns it.
  ([fname]
   (with-open [r (new java.io.BufferedReader (clojure.java.io/reader fname))]
     (let [sb (new StringBuilder)]
       (loop [c (.read r)]
         (if (neg? c)
           (str sb)
           (do
             (.append sb (char c))
             (recur (.read r)))))))))
```

EDIT: changed code a bit.  What was your intention with the #^String enc?

Comment: I tried as you did but I get this error now: Caused by: clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core$slurp-std-input

Comment: I am not sure if the "args" can be identified inside the slurp-std-input

Comment: You need to pass args to if in your main function now.

Comment: @RedDeckWins If you make the required edit, it would be reviewed before being accepted.

Comment: it wouldn't be an edit to this code - main would call `(slurp-std-input args)`

Comment: RedDeckWins: `#^String` is meant to be a type-hint on the input to prevent runtime reflection

Comment: After the changes I get this error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot open <("./scratch/small.txt")> as an InputStream

Comment: noisesmith: I changed only the (slurp-std-input args) but I still get the same error: CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: enc in this context, compiling:(regexdna/core.clj:19:3)    ps:I am new to Clojure

Answer (score 0):

RedDeckWins is on the right track, but I felt I could better help to clarify the problem in a separate answer, and also point out  a couple of other things while I'm at it.

This should at least fix the error that you're getting:

```
(defn slurp-std-input ;; (1)
  "Reads the standard input using the encoding enc into a string and
   returns it." ;; (2)
  ([fname] 
    (slurp-std-input fname (.name (java.nio.charset.Charset/defaultCharset))))
  ([fname ^String enc] ;; (3)
     (with-open [r (new java.io.BufferedReader 
                     (clojure.java.io/reader fname :encoding enc))]
       (let [sb (new StringBuilder)]
         (loop [c (.read r)]
           (if (neg? c)
             (str sb)
             (do
               (.append sb (char c))
               (recur (.read r)))))))))
```

Take note of three things above:

1. Here is where your problem lies -- you're defining a function with multiple arities, but the first line was `(defn slurp-std-input [args]`  -- this means the function has the arity 1, so anything after `[args]` must be a single definition of your fixed-arity function. That isn't what you want, so get rid of `[args]` and you should be good to go.
2. The convention in Clojure is to document functions via a string following the name of the function. This enables the user to obtain the documentation of your function via `(doc slurp-std-input)`.
3. Your type hinting syntax was slightly off. It should be `^String enc`, not `#^String enc`.

---

EDIT: I just realized your code uses `args`, which will no longer work with the corrections I've made, since the symbol `args` isn't bound to anything... I think I've figured out your intention, though. I've edited my code above. Your function should have the possible arities 1 and 2, not 0 and 1. You're at least passing one argument -- the filename -- and you can optionally pass an encoding as well.

---

EDIT #2: Here is a revised version that relies on [`clojure.core/slurp`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/slurp), which conveniently allows for optional parameters such as `encoding`:

```
(defn slurp-std-input
  "Returns the contents of a file as a string. 
   Optionally takes an encoding as a second argument."
  ([fname] (slurp fname))
  ([fname ^String enc] (slurp fname :encoding enc)))
```

Note that this is literally just a wrapper for `clojure.core/slurp`, so the fact that you're slurping a filename that comes from standard input is actually irrelevant. If I were to write a function like this, I would call it something like `slurp-plus` or `slurp'` or something.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just use Clojure's [slurp](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/slurp) function? Is there some special behavior you want for your slurping function?

Comment: OK, I think I get it now... you want your slurping function to allow for explicitly passing an encoding, otherwise using the default encoding. See my EDIT #2. Admittedly I don't know terribly much about Java, so let me know if I'm off the mark. I'm assuming that `slurp` uses `java.nio.charset.Charset/defaultCharset` by default.

Comment: with EDIT 1 I get this error:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot open <("./scratch/default.txt")> as an InputStream

Comment: Are you running this from a website, by chance? I got a similar error when trying to submit a Clojure solution on codeeval.com; they haven't quite worked out the kinks with Clojure yet. Other sites might be the same. If my hunch is correct, you might try running your code locally and see if that helps.

Comment: See: https://getsatisfaction.com/codeeval/topics/does_codeeval_work_for_clojure?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=topic_link